# I am working on the currency converter webapp with the fixer api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have successfully fetched all the values. But i want to populate all of the values {currencyOptions} into the "select" option which is in the another component. How can I do that .

```js
 const [currencyOptions, setCurrencyOptions] = useState([]);
  console.log(currencyOptions);
```

```js
  <div className="App">
      <h1>Convert Currency</h1>
      <CurrencyRow currencyOptions={currencyOptions} />
      <SiConvertio className="convert" />
      <CurrencyRow currencyOptions={currencyOptions} />
    </div>
```

Here is the currency option component which I

```js
const CurrencyRow = () => {
  return (
    //
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Input type="number" className="input" />
        <select>
          <option value="abx">abc</option>
        </select>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to populate your dropdown with your `currencyOptions` state. Assuming your state has all the items and it's a list you want to return an `option` element for each item when rendering your component, something like:

```
currencyOptions.map((currencyOption, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={currencyOption}>{currencyOption}</option>
));
```

Also try to use an id as the element `key` instead of the `index` if you have got one.

Comment: but how can i get the currencyOptions valus into another component

Comment: Pass it as props like you are doing and then in your `CurrencyRow` component receive them by defining it as a parameter. You can either define a `props` parameter and then get it from `props.currencyOptions` or you can destruct it this way: `{ currencyOptions }`.